# array element joining

Tags: php, arrays, join, merge

I want to use an array and after some calculation make a single element array and then marge these arrays.

like this

```
$array1[] = array('a'=1 , 'b'=4);
$array2[] array('c'=5);
result[] = array('a'=1 , 'b'=4 , 'c'=5);
```

i need a function in php to do this for me
tnx,

Comment: I've fixed up your syntax, but from the look of it, you need to spend some time learning basic PHP syntax. Go to the PHP manual http://php.net/  There is probably a version in your native tongue.

Comment: @dnagirl: On what grounds did you edit the syntax? It is pretty valid to have `$array[] = array('blah', 'blah', '...');`

Comment: It's not valid to have `$array[]=array('a'=1,'b'=4);` Though I admit I could have left the `[]` in.  Feel free to change it back if you like.

Comment: @dnagirl: That's what I was talking about the brackets. :)

Comment: `$result = $array1 + array2;`

Comment: @dnagirl you should not edit my syntax, my question was something else!

Answer (score 1):

All you need is [`array_merge()`](http://php.net/array_merge). Read [the documentation](http://php.net/array_merge).

Comment: it give me like this not what i said
$beginning = 'foo';
$end = array(1 => 'bar');
$result = array_merge((array)$beginning, (array)$end);
---> it show this to array: 
 Array
    (
        [0] => foo
        [1] => bar
    )

Comment: `$result = array_merge($array1, $array2);` this meets the conditions in your question. If your question is incomplete, please update it. Thanks.

Comment: Actually, given your problem description, this is exactly what you need. When the problem description is wrong, we cannot help you with right answers.

Comment: So for the code in the comment above, what is your desired result?

Answer (score 1):

The code you've pasted is not PHP code. Either way, you're probably looking for [`array_merge`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php).

Answer (score 0):

```
$result=array_merge($arr1,$arr2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't know, if your arrays really should look like this

```
$result[] = array_merge($array1[0], $array2[0]);
```

Update: The above may be obsolete, the question were changed

However, I guess, that you want something like this

```
$array1 = array('a'=1 , 'b'=4);
$array2 = array('c'=5);
$result = array_merge($array1, $array2);
```

[`array_merge()`](http://php.net/array_merge)

Comment: That code puts an array with two elements (a and c) into a new field of the result... it is not a merge.

Comment: @Martin Hohenberg: http://ideone.com/UYiuT Now read the question again ;) I _merge_ two arrays _of_ a field (note the `[0]`) as a new array as an element of the new array `$result`. Doesn't feel very useful, but that was the question (at least at the moment I wrote the question ... damn)

Comment: For everyone who is confused with the first part of the answer, take a look at the question edit. The question has been changed from its initial requirement. This does not deserve a down vote.

Comment: @Shef: Thanks for the note. However, the question were not edited by the OP, thus I don't know, what happens here :/

Comment: @KingCrunch: Maybe just add a note on that part of the answer. I think the OP had it right, and the edit was done with the thought that it was wrong to do it like that.

Answer (score 0):

use [`array_merge`](http://php.net/array_merge)

```
$array1 = array('a'=1, 'b'=4); // $array1[] is wrong, it appends to array1
$array2 = array('c'=5);
$result = array_merge($array1, $array2);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a joke?

```
$array1 = array('a' => 1 , 'b' => 4);
$array2 = array('c' => 5);
$result = array_merge($array1, $array2);
```